# Thread exiting message in .Net MVC console

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, verbosity, windows-console

I get this message: *the thread has exited with code 0* sometimes in the output window in debug mode when running a .net mvc c# application.

The application still works after these messages, it does not crash and there is no reason to crash, any ideas on what this mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Those are not errors -- those messages are simply telling you that a background thread has exited.  Zero means the thread ran and exited successfully.